# Can't bind to 'FormGroup' in angular 10

Tags: angular

> I am new to angular.
> I have created  a FormGroup , 'addLoanForm' in my CCCComponent.ts file.
> I have one module, 'Contacts.Module.ts' where I have imported
> both ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule

I kept getting the error : Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

```
**Module.ts**
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CCCComponent } from './ccc/ccc.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CCCComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule
  ]
})
export class ContactsModule { }
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ccc',
  templateUrl: './ccc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ccc.component.scss']
})
export class CCCComponent implements OnInit {

  addLoanForm : FormGroup;
  constructor() {
    this.addLoanForm=new FormGroup({
      'loanName':new FormControl()
    })
   }
   
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**html file**

```
<p>ccc works!</p>
<form [FormGroup] = "addLoanForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="loanName">
</form>
```

**app-routing.module**

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CCCComponent } from './contacts/ccc/ccc.component';

const routes: Routes = [{path : 'contact',component:CCCComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**error message**

```
Error: src/app/contacts/ccc/ccc.component.html:2:7 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

2 <form [FormGroup] = "addLoanForm">
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/contacts/ccc/ccc.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './ccc.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CCCComponent.
```

Comment: Have you tried `[formGroup]` (no capital f)?

Comment: The directive selector is formGroup, not FormGroup.

Comment: `formGroup` should start with lowercase ‘f’ in your HTML: `[formGroup]=“addLoanForm”`

Comment: I have made the change on the html file , but still same error message : Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

<form [formGroup]= "addLoanForm">

Answer (score 1):

it should be `formGroup`, according to the angular 10 docs [FormGroupDirective](https://v10.angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective#selectors) in your html-template, but its the same in newer versions:

```
<p>ccc works!</p>
<form [formGroup] = "addLoanForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="loanName">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the error means that angular dosen't find the property called FormGroup .
try  [formGroup] not [FormGroup] with f not F perhaps it will work
;)